# How to do an if or else with RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, list, discord, discord.py

I'm learning Python still, and I'm working on a bot for my Discord server. I want to make a command to check the availability of a skin (item) from my list (cat.json).

So a friend recommended me to use RegEx to identify the item and it worked as it should.

I want to apply rules to this system (if/else) but when I use if/else the command doesn't work right anymore...

> Here is my code:

```py
class Cat(commands.Cog):  # cog

    def __init__(self, client):  # cog setup.
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(  # command to check the skin in the list.
        name="skin",
        aliases=["s"]
    )
    async def skin(self, ctx, skin):
        list_ = json.load(open("cogs/cat.json"))  # ['battle queen katarina', 'katarina 02', 'graves 01']

        r = re.compile(f".*{skin}")  # regex filter.
        newlist = list(filter(r.match, list_))  # newlist = filtred regex list. 

        if skin in newlist:  # if skin (command) is in newlist:
            await ctx.channel.send(newlist)  # send the new list.
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'your skin ({skin}) is not available.')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Cat(client))  # cog
```

> Command: !s katarina

```py
'your skin (katarina) is not available.'
```

> Expected:
>
> Command: !s katarina

```py
['battle queen katarina', 'katarina 02']
```

> It would be perfect if it returned like this:

```py
'Katarina available skins: Battle Queen Katarina, Katarina 02'
```

Comment: Regex isn't the appropriate solution for this problem. Python has the `in` keyword, which you can use to check if the keyword occurs in a given name.

Comment: I would work more on that regex pattern... You can experiment using https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, I'll do it using `in` instead of `regex`, here's the first case:

```
@commands.command(  # command to check the skin_input in the list.
        name="skin_input",
        aliases=["s"]
    )
    async def skin(self, ctx, skin_input):
        skin_list = ['battle queen katarina', 'katarina 02', 'graves 01']
        newlist = list()  # store target skin

        for skin_item in skin_list:
            if skin_input in skin_item:     # if "katarina" in skin_item
                newlist.append(skin_item)   # add it into list

        if len(newlist) == 0:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'your skin_input ({skin_input}) is not available.')
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send(newlist)  # send the new list.
```

and the second

```
@commands.command(  # command to check the skin_input in the list.
        name="skin_input",
        aliases=["s"]
    )
    async def skin(self, ctx, skin_input):
        skin_list = ['battle queen katarina', 'katarina 02', 'graves 01']
        newlist = list()  # store target skin
        skin_found = ""

        for skin_item in skin_list:
            if skin_input in skin_item:     # if "katarina" in skin_item
                newlist.append(skin_item)   # add it into list, no need in this case
                skin_found += skin_item + ", "    # the return item (str) you want

        if len(newlist) == 0:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'your skin_input ({skin_input}) is not available.')
        else:

            await ctx.channel.send(f'{skin_input} available skins: {skin_found[:-2]}')  # send the new list.  # the[:-2]is to filter ", "
```

you can edit this into you way, may be without the unnecessary `new_list` :)

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it really worked
I will try to understand your code to learn how to do it by myself

Thank you very much

Comment: @balas That nice for you, welcome to stack btw!  remember to change the `skin_list` back to file I/O, I used hard code to test it.